# How to change color of part of route in here.com maps?

Tags: javascript, here-api

Is there a way to change the color of only parts of a route? I'm thinking of something similar to the way traffic is displayed (heavy traffic in red and light traffic in green along the same strip/route).

Answer (score 1):

You should make few routes in sequence with different color to accomplish that.